# Azure Function v2 Python deployed functions are not showing

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Locally the functions debug just fine, if I deploy via vscode to my azure function I get No HTTP Triggers found and the devops pipeline does not deploy triggers either.

I have "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing" set locally and as a function app setting.

Code is appropriately decorated

```
@app.route(route="functionname", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def functioname(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
```

Deployments succeed both ways but no functions show

Azure Pipeline shows correct files:
[image]

Azure function app files show function_app.py at the root folder

test function

```
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)    
@app.function_name("personas")
    @app.route(route="character-managment/personas")
    def personas(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse("ok", status_code=200)
```

Folder structure

[image]

Works locally

[image]

Comment: Add `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in Function App=>settings=>configuration=>Add New Application settings and re-deploy your application. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/9yYaajI.png)

Comment: @PravallikaKV
Still no functions showing and I added the application setting.
Even just deploying from vscode ignoring the pipeline
1:28:38 PM api: Syncing triggers...
1:29:12 PM api: Querying triggers...
1:29:14 PM api: No HTTP triggers found.
What url did you get that image from

Comment: The image is from my function app in Azure Portal. Can you provide your code or code structure?

Comment: @PravallikaKV added test function and folder structure image. I can add more let me know what would be of help.

Comment: Is your code working locally?

Comment: yes it is, I get all my functions and have been building them without issues hitting via http rests calls. I added an image of the terminal output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254818/discussion-between-pravallika-kv-and-user1552172).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment. I could see the deployed function in Azure function app.***

- Created a test default **Python v2 function** and deployed to **Azure function app**.

**Local:**

[image]

- ***Make sure you added the setting*** `"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"` ***in*** `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connection_string>"
  }
}
```

- ***Create and activate a new virtual environment using the commands:***

```
py -m venv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
```

[image]

- Include all the required packages in requirements.txt file.
- ***Install all the packages by running the command***
  `pip install -r requirements.txt` ***in the terminal.***

[image]

- Created a ***Python function app*** with ***Consumption plan*** and ***version 3.10***.
- ***Deployed the function with the command*** `func azure functionapp publish <function_app_name>`:

[image]

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

[image]

---

***I could also deploy the function with custom packages to Azure Function App.***

**requirements.txt:**

```
azure-functions
numpy
pandas
```

**Code(function_app.py):**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully with {arr} and {df}.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**Local:**

[image]

[image]
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[Create a Python function from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=python-mode-decorators)

You can also refer [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262) raised on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of reasons this could happen. In my case, it was that I copied the standard github Python .gitignore contents into my .funcignore, and this included an ignore for .py files. The .funcignore and .gitignore behaviors may be slightly different too.

I would suggest creating a new function totally from scratch in a new folder, verifying that it deploys successfully, and then checking all the differences one-by-one between that and your code (.funcignore, .gitignore, function_app.py, .vscode files, requirements.txt, host.json, local.settings.json).