# Azure Function App (Python v2) - blob_trigger function not showing after deployment

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk, azure-triggers

I have a Function App in a Python v2 programming model, which has a blob_trigger that is supposed to do sth on new blobs being created in a given storage account and container. I am working in VSCode. The function app works well when running locally with Azurite, however when I deploy it to Azure, there is no "blobTrigger" function under the Function App.

This is a code of my `function_app.py`:

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient

import datetime
import logging
import json
import os
import sys
import asyncio

_KV_SECRET_INPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING = os.environ["KV_SECRET_INPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING"]
STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME = os.environ["STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"]

async def read_blob_contents(connection_string: str, input_container_name: str, input_blob_name: str):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(input_container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(input_blob_name)

    try:
        blob_contents = await blob_client.download_blob(encoding = 'utf-8')
        return await blob_contents.readall()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error reading blob: {str(e)}")
        return None
    finally:
        await blob_service_client.close()


app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.function_name(name="blobTrigger")
@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path=STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME, connection="KV_SECRET_INPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING")

async def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream, context: func.Context) -> None:

    func_invoc_and_event_meta = json.dumps({
        "function_name" : context.function_name,
        "function_invocation_id" : context.invocation_id,
        'blob_name': myblob.name,
        'blob_length': myblob.length,
        'blob_uri': myblob.uri,
    }, indent=4)

    logging.info('Blob trigger processed an event:')
    logging.info(func_invoc_and_event_meta)

    logging.info("Attempting to read the blob...")
    
    try:
        blob_url = myblob.uri
        logging.info(f"blob_url: '{blob_url}'")
               
        # Read the contents of the blob asynchronously
        input_container_name = myblob.name.split('/', maxsplit=1)[0]
        input_blob_name = myblob.name.split('/', maxsplit=1)[1]
        blob_contents = await read_blob_contents(connection_string=_KV_SECRET_INPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING, input_container_name=input_container_name, input_blob_name=input_blob_name)
        logging.error("blob reading completed")

    except:
        logging.error("ERROR during blob read : ")
        logging.error(str(sys.exc_info()))
```

I made sure that the Function App has appropriate appsettings i.e. `KV_SECRET_INPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING` and `STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME`. The `KV_SECRET_INPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING` setting contains a connection string to the storage account that aims to store the data (new blobs), and it is a different storage account than the one that is linked to the function app through the `AzureWebJobsStorage` appsetting.

So what could be the problem?

On a related note, I also deployed another function app which is triggered by CRON, and for that one everything worked as expected.

Comment: Do you have the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=TRUE` in the function app configuration.

Comment: nope, when is this setting needed?

Comment: This setting needs to be added manually before deploying the function. Refer my [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927904/19991670) answer.

Comment: @PravallikaKV this did not help I am afraid. In the link to the other SO question there aren't many specifics about this either.

Comment: Are you trying with Consumption plan function app? If yes, try with any other plan like App Service Plan.

Comment: @PravallikaKV well I would really like to make it work under consumption plan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing and double checking everything I managed to narrow down issues to the following:

1. `requirements.txt` did not contain all the python libs that were referenced in the `import` statements in the `function_app.py` code
2. there was an application settings of the Function App that was misspelled in the application code in the `os.environ` statement, and as such could not be found

Fixing those fixed the problem. When deployed, the function correctly appears under the function app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. Set **FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION** to ~4. Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=portal#view-and-update-the-current-runtime-version) to guide you.
2. You have to use General Purpose storage account.

Comment: yup, had both already

Answer (score 0):

- If you have the setting `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` in `local.settings.json`, add the storage connection string as its value instead of `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`.
- Add the setting `"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"` in local.settings.json and in your Function App Environment variables.

---

I have created a Python V2 Azure function and deployed to Azure Function App with Consumption Plan.

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connection_string>"
      }
}
```

- **Deployment Status:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]